# Can type_info pointers be used to distingush types in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

I have a set of polymorphic C++ classes and they are all instantiated by the same module (Windows DLL). Now having two pointers to such classes and having called `typeid`:

```
SomeCommonBase* first = ...; //valid pointer
SomeCommonBase* second = ...; //valid pointer
const type_info& firstInfo = typeid( first );
const type_info& secondInfo = typeid( second );
```

can I compare retrieved `type_info` addresses

```
if( &firstInfo == &secondInfo ) {
   //objects are of the same class
} else {
   //objects are of different classes
}
```

or use `==`

```
if( firstInfo == secondInfo ) {
   //objects are of the same class
} else {
   //objects are of different classes
}
```

to detect whether objects are of (exactly) the same class or of different classes? Is it guaranteed to work when objects are instantiated from within the same module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm writing this, your code is

```
SomeCommonBase* first = ...; //valid pointer
SomeCommonBase* second = ...; //valid pointer
type_info& firstInfo = typeid( first );
type_info& secondInfo = typeid( second );
```

It should not compile because `typeid` returns a reference to `const`.

Worse, you are asking for type info about the pointers. Both pointers are of type `SomeCommonBase*`, so you're guaranteed that they are of the same type. Ask instead for type info about the pointed to objects.

That said, as @DeadMg remarked, you also need to use `operator==` to compare type info objects.

The C++ standard does not address the issue of dynamic libraries. But within any given Windows module you should be safe.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

You can only retrieve `const` type_info references, and you should always use `operator==`.

Comment: How could it happen that two calls of `typeid` to get typeinfo of objects of the same class in one DLL would return different typeinfo objects?

Comment: @sharptooth: Objects not created at the same time, their `type_info` object being determined at object creation time, and something relevant (like loading another DLL with identical types) happening in between?

Comment: @sharptooth: That's not the point. The point is that *if* this is true, then `operator==` will just compare the addresses. Why depend on this when you don't have to?