# Will equal type_info addresses mean equal types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

I'm micro-optimizing [code for identifying object types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7024414/57428). I assume I can use the following for checking whether two objects instantiated in the same module have identical types:

```
SomeCommonBase& first = ...;
SomeCommonBase& second = ...;
const type_info& firstInfo = typeid( first );
const type_info& secondInfo = typeid( second );

if( &firstInfo == &secondInfo || firstInfo == secondInfo ) {
   //identical types
} else {
   //different types
}
```

The logic is that once a `type_info` reference is returned the object behind that reference is guaranteed to [live until the module is unloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7024818/57428). So once a reference is returned no other object can occupy the same address.

So if addresses match then those are identical `type_info` objects and identical data types. If the implementation returns different `type_info` objects for the same type `type_info::operator==` is invoked and does additional check.

Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I believe Visual Studio might be doing this for you already. Take care not to be premature...

Comment: @Bo Persson: I carefully measured and looks like you're right - the difference is very small, I guess it only saves a function call. Anyway I don't mind changing one tiny piece of code to have a slight speedup everywhere.

Comment: clang inlines the compares, it looks like `(&a == &b || strcmp(a.name(),b.name())==0)`. So in that case, adding an extra address compare is redundant and the compiler will remove it.  In any case, you're likely to spend most of your time on the _failing_ compares, especially if you have a lot of types with long common prefixes in the name().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously.

Equal addresses mean that both pointers refer to the same object in memory. If the pointer is of type `type_info*`, then obviously it means the objects (i.e `first` and `second` in your case) passed to `typeid()` are of same type. After all, how can two pointers having same address, might refer to the different `type_info` objects, so as to become different type?